# Can't turn off Wireframe in Viewport all modes (It's a bug?)

Tags: 3d-view, interface, wireframe

Is already off "Viewport Overlays/Geometry/Wireframe"

Is already off [Object Properties/Viewport Display/Wireframe]

It don't have Wireframe modifier, either node wireframe.

Suddenly it happened out of nowhere!

Blender 2.8

How can I fix this please?

[image]

**EDITED:**

Wireframe is displayed in all modes: Solid, Material and Render.

I mean it shows:

- Solid + Wireframe.
- Material + Wireframe.
- Render + Wireframe.

I tried several things but the only thing that works is to turn off "Viewport Overlays / Extras".

But the normal thing is to be able to turn off the "wireframe" without having to do this because I also need to see the lights and cameras in the "viewport" and if I turn off "extras " You can no longer see the "wireframe", or the lights, or cameras, etc.

Comment: Thanks but I'm in a "Solid Mode".

Comment: When you say "wireframe" you mean transparent object and only wires on viewport or a solid object with wireframe on top of this? Share screenshot of your settings and your object just to have a visual

Comment: solid object with wireframe on top (already screenshot)

Comment: What if you append your object in a new scene?

Comment: did you try another blender version?

Comment: I think that maybe work 'cause when I create a new scene the same does not happen, but I want to know how resolve this without moving all to another scene.

Comment: @Chris I do not.

Comment: Can u provide blend file?

Comment: This happened to me when loading assets from an older blender version. Going into edit mode and back in object mode (with TAB) could solve it

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes when I go in and out of edit with TAB, the wireframe is removed but then it pops up anytime.

Comment: Now, I realized that if I don't have any additional Viewport in wireframe mode, the problem disappears, but it is not normal, and in other new scenes that error does not happen.

Comment: (No @Gorgious, I did not import anything from any previous version, I have done everything from scratch)

Comment: Then, the problem is the blend file, in cases like this, you do need to share your original file in order to see your settings. But it could be a file corruption, bug or something else

Comment: I think it could be a file corruption or a bug :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case I traced it to freestyle edges / marks, turning those off fixed the view. Technically, they weren't wireframe, but freestyle edges.

Answer (score -1):

Select the object and click [image] button. Then go into viewport display and uncheck wireframe.

Comment: The OP stated that wireframe was unchecked in the object viewport display. It's in his screenshot in fact. I'm having the same issue here